# tmpfs - auto create whole path when write to file

Tags: linux, directory, tmpfs

I have mounted **tmpfs** .e.g.

```
/tmspfs/cache
```

As we expect, so after restart server is ram empty and all content from mount is away. It is ok. But I have in my system some full path e.g. /tmpfs/cache/user1/file - error is /tmpfs/cache/user1/ is not exist.

I cant add some checks and rmdir to software.

**So question is - Is some way here, for auto create whole path before create file?**

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know the set of paths that you need to create ?

Comment: +1 to the question, I think it should be added to the tmpfs driver.
Another solution could be to use `bind` but it also requires to the folder to be created before binding

Answer (score 0):

Possible with LD_PRELOAD and some libraries, depending on the software.  The easiest thing might be to put something in rc.local that will create the directories as a final step in the boot procedure.

If you wanted to make sure the directories are there continuously, you could have a cron job running that created the dirs (using mkdir -p possibly).

Answer (score 0):

If you use `/etc/fstab` to define this mount you can just add `mkdir /tmpfs/cache/user1` to `/etc/rc.d/rc.local`, so it will be created on boot.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a persistent structure across reboots, the way you can implement this is by having a task in `root`'s `crontab`:

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/ionice -c3 -n7 /bin/nice -n 19 \
              /usr/bin/rsync -ah --stats --delete /path/to/persistent/backup /tmpfs/
```

Then in `/etc/rc.local` you ensure the structure is back in place at startup:

```
ionice -c3 -n7 nice -n 19 rsync -ahv --stats --delete /path/to/persistent/backup \
  /tmpfs/ 1>/dev/null
```

Of course, you need to adapt the `rsync` command to fit your specific needs.